# working on React App with Redux, axios:Uncaught TypeError: _api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.DonationCandidateAPI.fetchAll is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm a beginner to React and redux. I'm using Redux, Redux-React, Redux-thunk and axios for my first Crud app. the Error I'm getting is

> Uncaught TypeError: *api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.default.DonationCandidateAPI.fetchAll is not a function
> at DonationCandidateActions.js:10:1
> at index.js:16:1
> at boundActionCreators. [as fetchAllDonationCandidates] (bindActionCreators.js:8:1)
> at DonationCandidatesComponent.js:8:1
> at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
> at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
> at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
> at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
> at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
> at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)

my Reducer code is

```
import {ACTION_TYPE} from "../actions/DonationCandidateActions";
const initialState = {
list:[]
}
export const DonationCandidateReducer = (state=initialState,actions) => {
  switch (actions) {
      case ACTION_TYPE.FETCH_ALL:
          return {
            ...state,
            list:[...actions.payload]
          }

        default:
        return state;
     }
 }
```

API code is as folows

```
import axios from 'axios';
const baseurl = "http://localhost:42426/api/";
export default {
DonationCandidateAPI(url = baseurl + "donationcandidate")
{
    return {
        fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
        fetchById: (id) => axios.get(url+id),
        create: (newRecord) => axios.post(url,newRecord),
        update: (id,updatedRecord) => axios.put(url+id, updatedRecord ),
        delete: (id) => axios.delete(url+ id) 
    }
  }
}
```

and the file where I'm getting the error is my action file as below

```
import api from './api';
export const ACTION_TYPE = {
CREATE: "CREATE",
UPDATE:"UPDATE",
DELETE:"DELETE",
FETCH_ALL:"FETCH_ALL"
}
export const fetchAll =  () => dispatch => {
    api.DonationCandidateAPI.fetchAll()
    .then(
        response => {
            dispatch(
                {
                    type:ACTION_TYPE.FETCH_ALL,
                    payload:response.data
                }
            )
         },
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is in your export of `DonationCandidateAPI` function you are returning an object not a function. Also, you are missing function keyword while declaring `DonationCandidateAPI` function. Here is a fix:

```
export default function DonationCandidateAPI(url = baseurl + "donationcandidate") {
    return {
        fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
        fetchById: (id) => axios.get(url + id),
        create: (newRecord) => axios.post(url, newRecord),
        update: (id, updatedRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updatedRecord),
        delete: (id) => axios.delete(url + id)
    }
}
```

Also in your action.js code will be:

```
import DonationCandidateAPI from './api';
export const ACTION_TYPE = {
    CREATE: "CREATE",
    UPDATE:"UPDATE",
    DELETE:"DELETE",
    FETCH_ALL:"FETCH_ALL"
}
export const fetchAll =  () => dispatch => {
    DonationCandidateAPI.fetchAll()
    .then(
        response => {
            dispatch(
                {
                    type:ACTION_TYPE.FETCH_ALL,
                    payload:response.data
                }
            )
         },
    )
    .catch(err => console.log("hun aram ay" + err ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but this does not even change the error statement.